# DateSerial function doesn't work in SQL query

Tags: ms-access, vba

This function correctly returns the date 30 Sep 15:

```
Public Function ToDate() As Date

Dim MyYr As Integer

Select Case DatePart("m", Date)
        Case 1
               MyYr = DatePart("yyyy", Date) - 1
        Case Else
               MyYr = DatePart("yyyy", Date)
End Select

ToDate = DateSerial(MyYr, cmbMth, 1) - 1

End Function
```

But  it won’t work if I try to put it in here:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice, " & _
  "Sum(tblDisclosure.DBSFee) AS SumOfDBSFee, " & _
  "Sum(tblDisclosure.MyFee) AS SumOfMyFee, " & _
  "Count(tblDisclosure.ID) AS CountOfID, tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice " & _
  "From tblDisclosure " & _
  "GROUP BY tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice, tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice " & _
  "HAVING (((tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice) Is Not Null) AND " & _
      "((tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice) Between #10/31/2014# And ToDate)) "
```

I get the message *Enter parameter value - ToDate*.

It does work if I substitute `ToDate` with `DateSerial(2015,9,30)`.

Answer (score 2):

Or replace Today with DateSerial:

```
tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice Between #10/31/2014# And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()),0)
```

Comment: Avoiding a VBA call from a query  Priceless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"HAVING (tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice Is Not Null) AND
(tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice Between #10/31/2014# And ToDate()) "
```

The difference is a double parenthesis as part of the function call:  `ToDate()`.

Comment: I thought that must be the answer but having done that I now get an error message saying it's an undefined function.

Comment: Solved it! My function was referring to a control called cmbMth - this was causing the problem. I have define the month in a different way and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I helped solve it.  But I propose you try Gustav's answer.  He took the time to analyze your function and provided good use of built-in functions.  I am upvoting his although I haven't tested.

Comment: Gustav's answer didn't help I know that already. The point of saying that it worked with DateSerial(2015,9,30 was only to show that my code wasn't complete rubbish. It was essential to get ToDate = DateSerial(MyYr, cmbMth, 1) - 1 to work.